# How to read a text file in Python that is never saved

Tags: python, file, save

I have a log file containing data that I need to read in real-time to check when certain events have occurred. The way the log files work is that there is one "live" log (the one I need to monitor) and many archived logs. When the "live" log gets to a certain size it is then saved as an archived log. With my current code I am able to monitor a local text file for changes being written to it:

```
    import time

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("folder1\\folder2\\.txt", "r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        print(">>> " + line)
```

However the key issue is that this only picks up that data has been written to the file after I have saved the changes. In the file I need to monitor a save never occurs until it reaches a certain size. This is what is currently preventing me from reading any of the data being written to it in real-time, it instead all comes through at once when it is saved as an archived log.

My question is this, is there any way possible to read the data being written to it when the file is not being actively saved?

Comment: without writing a lot of code probably not :(, you could try to save what you write (before saving) to a string and read that

Comment: @KetZooomer - The issue is that I am not the one writing the file so the only option is to read this log file

Comment: @KetZoomer there's a pretty strict boundary between processes, and unless the creator of the log file wants to share the bits of memory where it's storing that log before flushing it to disk, there is no way for you to access it using normal means.  Check and see if the software generating the log offers some other means of accessing the data.

Comment: Oh, if you are not writing to the file, nope, no way to do that :(